# Service always in STOPPED state

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-services

I have a problem with a service, when I try to install it like this :

```
sc create MemoryStatus binpath= "C:\Users\rock\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ServiceInC\Release\ServiceInC.exe"
```

I get a message in cmd that service is installed successfully, but when I take a look on it via Task Manager it is always in stopped state. The one more thing is that service is not even started, cause I dont see any log messages.

It seems like there is some problem with permissions or something like that, can you please help me with that?

MY main Service function is :

```
void ServiceMain(int argc, char** argv) 
{ 
    int error; 

    ServiceStatus.dwServiceType        = SERVICE_WIN32; 
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState       = SERVICE_START_PENDING; 
    ServiceStatus.dwControlsAccepted   = SERVICE_ACCEPT_STOP | SERVICE_ACCEPT_SHUTDOWN;
    ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode      = 0; 
    ServiceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0; 
    ServiceStatus.dwCheckPoint         = 0; 
    ServiceStatus.dwWaitHint           = 0; 

    hStatus = RegisterServiceCtrlHandler(
        "MemoryStatus", 
        (LPHANDLER_FUNCTION)ControlHandler); 
    if (hStatus == (SERVICE_STATUS_HANDLE)0) 
    { 
        // Registering Control Handler failed
        WriteToLog("Registering Control Handler failed");
        return; 
    }  
    // Initialize Service 
    error = InitService(); 
    if (error) 
    {
        // Initialization failed
        WriteToLog("Initialization failed");
        ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState       = SERVICE_STOPPED; 
        ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode      = -1; 
        SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus); 
        return; 
    } 
    // We report the running status to SCM. 
    ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState = SERVICE_RUNNING; 
    SetServiceStatus (hStatus, &ServiceStatus);

    MEMORYSTATUS memory;
    // The worker loop of a service
    while (ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState == SERVICE_RUNNING)
    {
        char buffer[16];
        GlobalMemoryStatus(&memory);
        sprintf(buffer, "%d", memory.dwAvailPhys);
        int result = WriteToLog(buffer);
        if (result)
        {
            ServiceStatus.dwCurrentState       = SERVICE_STOPPED; 
            ServiceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode      = -1; 
            SetServiceStatus(hStatus, &ServiceStatus);
            return;
        }

        Sleep(SLEEP_TIME);
    }
    return; 
}
```

One more thing that I forgot to say, when I force run service frfom task manager it seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command `sc create...` only creates the service, it does not attempt to start it. From `sc /?`:

> create----------Creates a service. (adds it to the registry).

To attempt to start the service either do it via the Services Control Applet or by running:

> sc start MemoryStatus